# cholesky decomposition of special correlation matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose the covariance matrix is of the form $A = aI +bJ$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the matrix of all ones. Assume that Cholesky decomposition is possible. Do we get a nice analytic expression for Cholesky decomposition of $A$?

Comment: Note that a Cholesky decomposition is necessarily possible for a covariance matrix.  In general, $aI + bJ$ will have a Cholesky decomposition if and only if $a \geq 0$ and $a \geq -nb$, where $n$ is the size of $A$.

Comment: $A$ satisfies all these properties.

Answer (score 0):

The Cholesky factorization of $aI$ is

$aI=R^{T}R$

where $R=\sqrt{a}I$.  This is easy to compute.

The matrix of all ones, $J$ is a rank one matrix, so

$J=vv^{T}$

where

$v=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{array}
\right]
$.

Thus

$aI+bJ= a + bvv^{T}$

This is a rank-one update (or "downdate" if $b<0$) of $aI$.  There are simple and fast algorithms for the Cholesky factorization of a rank-one update to a matrix that can be used.  In MATLAB this is implemented in the cholupdate() function.